# Wireless adapter switches off at end of boot up

Tags: wireless-networking, adapter

I have Sony Vaio desk top running Windows Vista Home premium. When I boot up, the wireless adapter is enabled but just as the boot up is finishing, the adapter is switched off. I have downloaded the latest driver but it makes no difference.
I can get around the problem by disabling the adapter before I close down and then enabling it when I boot up again but this is tedious.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Has it always been this way, or did the behavior change recently?  Also, if you hibernate the desktop, does the behvior change?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a conflict between softwares. Or yourself getting lost when another software takes over. The windows vista platform has a wireless setup and software capability in it. You say you download and install drivers for the hardware also.  That could indicate that you are also trying to use the software that comes with many of the wireless devices, not just a driver?

I had the same Issue one time myself, I had to pick one :-) either let winders setup the wireless and figure it all out. Or use the software they supply with one additional feature I did not need. I uninstalled thier software, keeping just the Driver itself, and use the OS for the configure and setup.

Some tests would be to disable temporarily thier software at startup or run places in the registry (or service), and see if that works more like you expect.